# custom setting value is different in trigger on test

Tags: apex, trigger, customsetting

When I execute this code in anonymous

`System.debug(Auction_Trigger_Switch__c.getOrgDefaults().On__c);`

It returns a boolean value of `true` as expected.

But when I do this in my trigger on an if statement:

```
trigger AuctionTrigger on Auction__c (before insert, before update, after insert, after update, after delete) {

    AuctionTriggerHandler handle = new AuctionTriggerHandler(trigger.new, trigger.oldMap, trigger.old, trigger.isInsert, trigger.isUpdate, trigger.isDelete);

    System.debug(Auction_Trigger_Switch__c.getOrgDefaults().On__c);   
    if(Auction_Trigger_Switch__c.getOrgDefaults().On__c) {
        if(trigger.isBefore) {
            if (trigger.isInsert)   handle.beforeInsert();
            if (trigger.isUpdate)   handle.beforeUpdate();
        }

        if (trigger.isAfter) 
        {
            if (trigger.isInsert)   handle.afterInsert();
            if (trigger.isUpdate)   handle.afterUpdate();
            //if (trigger.isDelete)   handle.afterDelete();
            //if (trigger.isUndelete) handle.afterUndelete();
        }
    }


}
```

It returns `false`. What is going on?

Screenshots of my custom setting
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you created data in custom setting? http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/02/08/using-hierarchy-custom-settings-in-salesforce-com/

Comment: @RatanPaul I set the default org values. Check the latest screenshot.

Comment: could it be I need to create the custom setting in my test?

Comment: Are you checking the debug in test class? If you calling trigger from test class then yes you have to create in test class.

Comment: @RatanPaul that was it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you checking the debug in test class?
 If you calling trigger from test class then yes you have to create data in test class.

Because org data will not be visible in test class. You have to create data in test class

Comment: I thought a custom setting record was different from a object record...